# Svn equivalent of p4 opened

Tags: svn, version-control, perforce

Is there an equivalent command to 'p4 opened' in svn?

Comment: Per @duskwuff: "For those of us who aren't familiar with Perforce, what does p4 opened do?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like [`svn status`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re26.html) performs the same function. This command is what I commonly use for a "where am I?" command. It shows work that I've done but not yet committed to the repository.

I'm not familiar with Perforce, but I got info from [p4 opened](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/opened.html).